# Fixing Broken RSS feed, duplicate items via "pubDate"

Tags: rss, feed, syndication

I am trying to subscribe to an RSS feed for a fighter's history via MixedMartialArts.com, but this particular website updates the pubDate for each of the fights, causing duplicates every time the pubDate is updated.

http://www1.mixedmartialarts.com/?go=rss.fighterRecord&pid=8878384A5C892D13

However, other attributes of each  remain the same, particularly <title>.

What can I do (maybe via Yahoo Pipes, or other normalizer) to fix this issue temporarily until they correct the problem on their end?

Comment: Maybe using http://superfeedr.com will help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader), and find that it is very good at dealing with malformed feeds.